# Angular function is called hundred of times on mouse move

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have the following code with material table which multiselects columns. What I have noticed is that on every mouse move `isAllSelected()` is called hundreds of times. Why is this happening. I thought it should only be called when check box was clicked

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="checkbox">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-header-cell>

    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let priority">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(priority) : null"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(priority)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Colour Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="colour">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Colour</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let priority">{{priority?.colour}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let priority">{{priority?.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let priority; columns: displayedColumns;" class="contact" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

and the .ts file

```
export class AdminPrioritiesSettingsComponent {

 dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

 selection = new SelectionModel<PriorityDto>(true, []);
 displayedColumns = ['checkbox', 'colour', 'name'];


 isAllSelected() {
    console.log(this.selection.hasValue());
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() : this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if related but `(change)="$event ?` should be replaced with `(change)="$event.checked ?`. The boolean status is contained in the `checked` property of the event object.

Comment: Have a look here - https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: @ShubhamBhokare I got this example from official angular material examples

Comment: @pantonis: Could you please link that example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaaxkpqmojgv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.html

Comment: @pantonis, That is fine, but isAllSelected() function will be executed every time change detection is initiated in component. Be it mouse-move mouse-click or any.

Comment: what is the alternative to make this work correctly without all these unnecessary calls?

Comment: Go through the medium article I shared above. It has 2 strategies, any of them can be used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, `isAllSelected()` function is called via `masterToggle()`. The change of `$event`, is triggered by your mouse movement, consequently calling the `masterToggle()`. Is this your problem? In that case, you might wanna subscribe to the click event.